# Wrong SQL statement join table one to many hibernate JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

i have two Entitys/Tables and want to Join each other.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTIKEL")
public class Artikel{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String artikelbezeichnung;
    private int artikelnummer;
    private Float preis;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "artikel")
    private List<Artikeldetails> artikeldetails;
```

and the second Table/Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ARTIKELDETAILS")
public class Artikeldetails {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String artikeldetail;
    private String artikelcustom;
    private String artikelselektion;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="artikel_id", nullable = false)
    private Artikel artikel;
```

MY JPA Respository (Query)

```
@Query(value="SELECT artikel FROM Artikel artikel JOIN FETCH artikel.artikeldetails where artikel.artikelnummer = :artikelnummer")
    List<Artikel> findByArtikelnummer(@Param("artikelnummer") int artikelnummer);
```

what did Hibernate Generate:

```
select a1_0.id,a1_0.artikelbezeichnung,***a2_0.artikel_id***,a2_0.id,a2_0.artikelcustom,a2_0.artikeldetail,a2_0.artikelselektion,a1_0.artikelnummer,a1_0.preis 
from artikel a1_0 join artikeldetails a2_0 on a1_0.id=***a2_0.artikel_id ***
where a1_0.artikelnummer=?
```

the Problem is that a1_0.artikel_id not exists! The SQL Statement must look like:

```
select a1_0.id,a1_0.artikelbezeichnung,a2_0.id,**a2_0.id**,a2_0.artikelcustom,a2_0.artikeldetail,a2_0.artikelselektion,a1_0.artikelnummer,a1_0.preis 
from artikel a1_0 join artikeldetails a2_0 on a1_0.id=**a2_0.id **
where a1_0.artikelnummer=?
```

Can anyone help? I DISAPAIR ON HIBERNATE!

Answer (score 0):

If you define your variable artikel in the entity Artikeldetails with `@JoinColumn(name="artikel_id", nullable = false)`, then it's normal that hibernate is generating the join of the 2 tables with the column artikel_id from artikeldetails against the column id from artikel table. Nothing wrong here.

On the other hand, if you want to join the 2 tables with the column id from artikeldetails against the column id from artikel table, then you can have only one artikeldetail per artikel and therefore your variable artikeldetails in the entity Artikel is wrong: it should be a `@OneToOne` and the type should not be a list of Artikeldetails but simply a Artikeldetails.